# Buscar dato duplicado array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array de la siguiente forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IP] => 172.30.224.232
            [Equipo] => Space-saving
            [CodPat] => 111
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [IP] => 172.26.35.108
        [Equipo] => Desktop Case
        [CodPat] => 11212
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [IP] => 172.30.224.247
        [Equipo] => Space-saving
        [CodPat] => 123123
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [IP] => 172.30.224.247
        [Equipo] => Space-saving
        [CodPat] => 2323232
    )
```

Tengo un ciclo para poder extraer los datos de las IPs

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 255; $i++){
    $ip = "172.26.35.".$i;
    foreach ($ips as $val) {
    if ($val['IP']==$ip) {
        $existe = true;
        $equipo = $val['Equipo'];
        $codPat = $val['CodPat'];
        break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Lo que no se como resolver es que identifique las IPs duplicadas... ya intente con funciones como array_count_values(), array_map(), in_array(), etc. pero aun no logro que funcione así...

Alguna sugerencia? 
gracias!

Comment: Explica el resultado final que quieres. El código suponte que encuentra un duplicado... ¿qué hay que hacer luego, quitarlo del array, sacarlo en otro array, modificarlo...?

Comment: actualmente en una tabla me imprime por fila IP, Equipo, Codigo, el resultado que quiero es que por IP duplicada me imprima los códigos de cuales están duplicadas, en la misma fila...